# Assigning a value to Python list doesn't work?

Tags: python

The following code works properly for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
N = int(raw_input("N="))
l=[]
i = 0
while i<N:
   n = raw_input("e"+str(i)+"=")
   l.append(n) 
   i = i+1   
print l
```

**But**, why can't I simplify it by using `l[i] = raw_input("e"+str(i)+"=")` instead?

Example: (doesn't work)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
N = int(raw_input("N="))
l=[]
i = 0
while i<N:
   l[i] = raw_input("e"+str(i)+"=")
   i = i+1   
print l
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use indexing (e.g. `obj[x]`) to access or modify items that already exist in a `list`. For example, the following works because the positions in the list that we are accessing already exist:

```
>>> chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> chars[0]
'a'
>>> chars[0] = 'd'
>>> chars
['d', 'b', 'c']
```

However, accessing or modifying items at positions that *do not exist* in a `list` **will not work**:

```
>>> chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> chars[3]
...
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> chars[3] = 'd'
...
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> chars
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you want to simplify your code, try: (it uses a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
N = int(raw_input("N="))
l = [raw_input("e" + str(i) + "=") for i in range(N)]
print l
```

Comment: you shorter than my code,I must change to this approach ,thanks

Comment: you mean for obj[x] we only access not can assigned?

Comment: You can access *and* assign, but only to positions in a `list` that *already exist*.

Comment: your answer is perfect ,But I dont understand what you have say more here? Could you give me some example about this? thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think in your second example, I think you mean why you can't directly assign list elements.  The answer to that is because the elements have not been *initialized* ie. the list size is still 0. You could do

```
l = [0] * N
```

To initialize the list to N elements with a value of 0.

Or you could just do:

```
l.append(raw_input("e"+str(i)+"="))
```

Comment: I do agree. My experience was that I did not initialize the list beforehand, therefore the value could not be assigned into the list. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A value has to exist before you can assign to it. The first time round the loop, `i` is 0 and `l[0]` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because the `[]` operator doesn't work like that with lists. It lets you access an existing index in the list, nothing more.

Edit: you can override that behaviour in your own class if you wrap a list, should you for some reason need it. See here:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/sequence-types.html